# regarding difference between siebel crm and microsoft dynamic crm

Tags: dynamics-crm, siebel

hi every now i would like to learn one cource.i think to learn any CRM cource that i seither SIEBEL CRM or DYNAMIC CRM but which one is better to learn and in which one jobs r good .plz could some plz suggest me  .thanks

Comment: Questions about using existing software generally belong on superuser.com or (if it's software for a server) serverfault.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dynamics crm from microsoft would be easier

Comment: thanks for responding my q.but  how about jobs for these cource there r jobs  for freshers r for 2+ exp.

Comment: you need to first learn and certify then join any company that does crm implemenation for clients

Answer (score 3):

From a personal experience using vtiger CRM and Siebel CRM and Dynamics, i see that Dynamics CRM can be the most appropriate CRM to learn and to consider it a starting point in your Career. 
MS Dynamics CRM is properly supported by Microsoft and most of the Corporations would prefer going through Dynamics since in a simple Quality/Price Ratio, Dynamics always wins against all other Popular CRM solution specially SAP CRM and Siebel CRM 
Close your eyes and go Directly through Dynamics !

Answer (score 2):

Oracle has a 16% marketshare, Microsoft's is less than 3-4%, but I feel like Microsoft is poised to gain in the CRM market, since their Dynamics suite continues to mature and seems to have a lot of investment. If you learn Siebel you're going to be dealing primarily with large companies, while Dynamics will likely be medium to small businesses. This question comes down mostly to geography and skills, if you live in the USA and know .NET and MS SQL, I'd say go dynamics, otherwise I might lean towards Siebel.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft CRM has better native out of the box integration with the Microsoft Office line of products.  If a company is aligned with Microsoft products (Outlook, Word, Excel), it will be much less expensive for them to implement Microsoft CRM in the long run.  Other CRM vendors have integrations with the products but it is not at a native level.  CRM implementations are wrought with failure, with a big factor to that being that users can't use the product efficiently.  Since Microsoft CRM has all of these built-in integrations, it has a one-up in user adoption on its competitors.  It has a great model for CRM with out of the box modules for Sales, Service, and Marketing, along with a extensible database model that can be configured by any power user (with a little bit of training).  Microsoft is very dedicated to the product and releases quarterly update rollups and comes out with a major release about ever 2 to 3 years.  Microsoft CRM offers companies the ability to have their CRM hosted with Microsoft, hosted with a partner, or on-premise, whereas many of the other vendors only offer a cloud or on-premise option, but not both.  I've been working with a Dynamics CRM partner for about 4 years and the job market for Microsoft CRM (and most Microsoft technologies) has been very good in my experience.